# git error: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Input/output error

Tags: git, github

I am using eclipse to work on my project. I cloned the source using https protocol in eclipse, however when running a script that I made I get an error for git when trying to commit changes to github.

> could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Input/output error

Seems to be just configuration and not the script itself. Any suggestions on what needs to be configured?

Comment: Before trying to automate stuff, you should try to manually push & pull to the repository to verify that it is set up correctly. The "input/output error" suggests that git is trying to get some input from the user and that the fact that it's called from a script stops that from working.

Comment: @JoachimSauer It does push when I enter my username/password. How to add that as a default option so when I do automate it, I don't need to provide it